# Why can't barium be produced in a supernova explosion?

Tags: nuclear-physics, astrophysics, stars, supernova, nucleosynthesis

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlBG_A4Djp4), Michael Merrifield claims that the elements barium, lanthanum and cerium cannot be produced within supernova explosions, and that they must be produced via a slower neutron-aggregation-plus-beta-decay process known as the [s-process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-process).

Now, I imagine that this is a bit of an exaggeration, and indeed the Wikipedia page for the s-process suggests that it's not entirely a black-and-white process, but it still seems that those elements are produced much less efficiently than their neighbours during the rapid neutron-capture events of the various supernova types.

Why is this, and what is the essential physics behind this lagoon of sorts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important factor for r-process and s-process is a competition between
beta decay lifetime $\tau_{\beta}$ and speed of neutron capture $\tau_{n\gamma}$ (*better: time between two neutron captures, not really a speed*).

In the following picture, the boxes stand for stable nuclei. Once the s/r-process stops, everything else will (with time) decay to something stable following the North-West direction diagonal lines.

[image]

The **s-process** is a typical in a situation, where $\tau_{n\gamma} \gg \tau_{\beta}$. Nucleosynthesis will never go far beyond the stability line - it is always in the neighborhood of the boxes - the *left-to-right* line and then one NW $\beta$-decay line.

On the opposite, **r-process** arises in the situation, where $\tau_{n\gamma} \ll \tau_{\beta}$ for nuclei close to stability. Before the long-lived isotope decays, it gets one more neutron and the nucleosynthesis pushes all isotopes far from stability. Until the $\beta$-decay lifetimes are short enough to compete with the neutron capture.

Once the nucleosynthesis is **switched off**:

- s-process stays more or less as it was.
- r-process isotopes $\beta$-decay, until they reach the stability.

And now you can see in the picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isXPg.gif), that sometimes these decay chains end surprisingly at some **blue** boxes, that effectively **shield** some isotopes from being generated by r-process. This way - blue are the isotopes not reachable by s-process (maybe with low probability, which means low amounts) and red are the isotopes not-reachable by r-process (I can imagine some extremely rare scenarios, but it is not the point, is it?)

BTW - yellow isotopes are shielded from both processes - and their origin is still a question.

The next picture just illustrates the different peaks in abundances, $Sr$ has N~50, $Ba$ N~82 magic numbers, while the r-process nuclei have hit the magic numbers somewhere very far South-East in Terra Incognita and they have brought the information back.

[image]

Edit:

I picked-up the images randomly from web. The first one, I can see is used in https://answersingenesis.org/astronomy/solar-system/discussion-stellar-nucleosynthesis/ or https://uvachemistry.com/tag/s-process/ . The other one should be inside http://slideplayer.com/slide/10684436/ (I see it is from Maria Lugaro, an expert to the topic).  The color codes - there is something is the text, but I cn cite the description from ref:  *The isotopes represented by white boxes result from either the s or r process. The blue boxes represent isotopes that result only from the r process, while the red boxes are s-only isotopes. The yellow boxes represent isotopes produced by proton capture.*

Comment: Can you clarify the colour code on your first image, and link to sources for both?